# PyDev doesn't autocomplete variables docstring based

Tags: python, pydev

I'm using Eclipse 3.8 with PyDev (latest in update channel). The doctring is generated, but pyDev doesn't use it.

```
def reporthook(self, count, blockSize, totalSize):
    '''
    Comment Example
    :param count: description of count param
    :type count: int
    :param blockSize: description of blockSize param
    :type blockSize: int
    :param totalSize:description of totalSize param
    :type totalSize:int
    '''
    count. # <-- Here with CTRL + Space dont autocomplete
```

Answer (score 0):

PyDev shoud indeed be able to give you code-completion from the docstring information (as shown in http://www.pydev.org/manual_adv_type_hints.html).

Now, not sure why it's not working in your case... (just tried the same case you provided here and it worked without any issues) maybe there was a bug in the version you're using? Have you tried updating PyDev to the newest version (although note that you also have to get a newer version of Eclipse -- the latest PyDev requires Eclipse 4.6).

Answer (score -1):

Your question is confusing. The docstring you give has nothing to do with autocompletion.
This is two different things.

If you want the documentation of your method to show up, press :

```
YourClass. # Ctrl+Space
```

Then clicking `reporthook` in `PyDev` will display the whole code of this method (including the docstring).

Otherwise, if you are asking for autocompletion, Python being dynamically typed, `PyDev` has no reason to show up anything by pressing `count. # Ctrl+Space` (with the `dot`), as count (even if it was a class - which is not the case), could not be recognized as such.

By another hand, docstrings are only available at runtime, so `PyDev` has no reason to use it while editing scripts (excepted if the requested module or feature comes from an already compiled module : for example pressing `numpy. # Ctrl+Space` would provide the doc for its functions, because it is a module loaded in memory by `PyDev` at startup).

I suggest that you have a look [here](http://www.pythonforbeginners.com/basics/python-docstrings/).

Or maybe, refreshing the `Python Interpreter` would help (Windows > Preferences > PyDev > Python Interpreter > Apply > Check the interpreter > Press OK), your script being in the `PYTHONPATH`...

Hope this is helpful...

Comment: Also, to my experience PyDev works quite better under Linux than Windows. (Don't know anything about OSX).

Comment: i want PyDev autocomple my var by type

Comment: Yes I got that, but I'm not sure this is possible. That's what I attempted to tell... If someone demonstrates the opposite, I'm totally disposed to hear the arguments.